# javascript function and html onclick property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a javascript on my page and I want to refer to a function with the `onclick` property. How would I do this, how would I change my following code so that is actually runs the script correctly?

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 function dosomething()
  {
   alert('I just did something');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Kortingscode" onclick="dosomething()">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the function is inside of the ready so it is not global.

Comment: You should use the document.ready just when you want to run something at that moment. What you want to achieve is to create a function that can be called globally, so just declare it without that document.ready

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to trigger html onclick event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624670/using-jquery-to-trigger-html-onclick-event)

Comment: There's no reason to use `$(document).ready` in this case.  The code within doesn't need the document for anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `dosomething` function outside the `ready` function on a global scope

Comment: On stackoverflow it works, but it doesn't work in my fiddle. Code works fine now.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't understand, does it work now or not?

Comment: Yes it works fine now. Thank you. I will mark this answered in a couple minutes.

Answer (score 2):

An other solution is adding the event to the button on the document.ready

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];

   button.onclick=function(){
      alert('Hi');
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Kortingscode">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using document ready event?

You have two different solution:

ONE: declare your function as global (outside document ready)

```
function dosomething() {
 alert('I just did something');
}
```

TWO: declare your function as jquery event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".btn-default" ).click(function() {
    alert('I just did something');
  })
)};
```

Make sure your javascript code is inside a `<script></script>` tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "declare your function as a jquery event"? I want to call the function within the onclick property, how would it look like, could you refer me to an example of some sort?

Comment: As I already said, just don't use $(document).ready( but put directly the function name (so it becomes global)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use jquery for that.

First load the jquery script.

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js""></script>
```

Then

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default Kortingscode" value="Kortingscode">
```

The jquery:

```
   <script>
    $(".Kortingscode").click(function(){
        alert("The button was clicked.");
    });
   </script>
```