# Trigger function on click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a series of DIVs like this:

```
<div class="a" onclick="Test();"></div>
<div class="b" onclick="Test();"></div>
<div class="c" onclick="Test();"></div>
...

function Test(){
...
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: "somedata=" + somedata,
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: "html",
   success: function (msg) {           
      var owl = $('.carousel-Class');
      owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel');
      owl.owlCarousel({
         ...
      })  
}
```

and I want trigger this function on page load on a specific div (I.E. div with class 'b'):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".b").trigger('click');
})
```

The result is that the Owl Carousel items don't appear correctly, they have different size than they should have. For appear correctly I need to do an extra click on the DIV.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to trigger html onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624670/using-jquery-to-trigger-html-onclick-event)

Answer (score 0):

Why simulate the trigger and not just call the function Test() on your ready() function.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    Test();
})
```

However it seems you have a concurency problem, try putting:

```
async: false
```

as a parameter of your ajax call to confirm it.

Comment: On document ready I need to call this function for a specified DIV not for all.